# summation of array data in php

Tags: php, arrays, sum, addition

```
<?php
 $price=$product_mrp;
 $qty=$cart_product_qty;
 $total=$price*$qty;
 $total_array=array($total);
 $total_amount=array_sum($total_array);
 echo $total_amount;
 ?>
```

I'm getting answer Total amount separate like 5 6. not 11. the code is inside while loop. I want to show total summation amount 11. guys please solve this issue .

Comment: `the code is inside while loop.`-> where? please post full code, so that we can help

Comment: Thanks Its working ...

Comment: then please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

What i understand accroding to that do below changes in your code:-

1.write `$total_array=[];` before your `while()` loop.

2.change `$total_array=array($total);` to `$total_array[]= $total;` inside `while()` loop.

3.Put these two lines outside of the `while()` loop.

```
$total_amount=array_sum($total_array);
echo $total_amount;
```

Comment: Ironic how your answer got downvoted but the incomplete question got upvoted.

Comment: @Andreas  i am astonished too. I am sure what i have given will work for OP 100%

Comment: Me too. But I'll wait for op to show the full code. By the looks of it, there may be more improvements that can be done. I'll give it a +1 just so that it rises above the other answer that is wrong.